# Gradle Error :"that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME"

Tags: android, android-studio, java-home

I have faced this error many times and fixed it also. But this time when I updated my android studio to the 2.2.2   and trying to load the project that was made on android studio 2.0 . Its giving me the following error.

[image]

and the path of the jdk is as and I have chnged tha following path to my valid jdk path but of no use. 
[image]

Please tell me what shoudl I do . My studio is running well with all other projects but that project was made on android 2.0 and with other machine in our company.

**Please help me I have stucked here for weeks**

Comment: What output do the commands `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%` in command prompt give (assuming you are on Windows)?

Comment: you need to update sdk as well.

Comment: i have updated sdk too and all other projects are working just fine

Comment: You need to install Oracle JDK 1.8 and configure `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: I am on windows 7 , tell me how to run these comands ,

Comment: echo %JAVA_HOME% this comands prints jdk1.7.0_79  
and echo %PATH%  prints 
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wb
owsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin

Comment: Your `JAVA_HOME` should be set to the full path of the directory, not just jdk1.7.0_79

Comment: what should be full path

Comment: Full path is something like `C:\Programs Files\JAVA\jdk_1.7`

Answer (score 4):

This error usually means what it says, you are trying to use a JRE instead of a JDK. The `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre` folder is not the folder you should be using, you should be using the directory of a JDK installation (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111`). You will also need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point at the same directory.

If you don't have a JDK you can download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html